# How to execute JS file only when user click

Tags: javascript

The Google Places javascript file is in my footer (shown below).
I'm trying to NOT load this JS file until the user clicks the page , or even better clicks a particular div (class = .searchbox2). Basically, don't load Google JS until user click page.
Thanks!

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=false&libraries=places&region=AU&language=en&key=xxxxxxxxxx"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For something like this, I would recommend Filament Group's [`loadJS`](https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadJS). You could use it as follows:

```js
// assuming loadJS is included on the page

const searchBox = document.querySelector('.searchbox2');
const mapsApi = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js' +
  '?v=3.exp&signed_in=false&libraries=places' + 
  '&region=AU&language=en&key=xxxxxxxxxx';

searchBox.addEventListener('click', function () {
  loadJS(mapsApi, function () {
    // any code here will run once the Maps API script has loaded
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: Adding a library in order to append a script to the DOM is not necessary.

Comment: @wuerfelfreak I've added an example. :-)

@sbolel I wouldn't class `loadJS` as a library but rather a function.

Comment: Tried the above code , it does not work.